# doctrine best relation 3 tables to 1 file table - practice / perfromance

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am googling for some days and can't decide with will be correct. all of them work but which could be best practice/performance

I have some tables:

```
1. documents
2. envelopes
3. contracts

x. Files
```

each 1-3 tables have many Files. 1-3 are NOT related together

variants:

1. relation by columns 1-3 table one-to-many and Files to each table many-to-one

File table could look like this

```
    id; name; documentsID; evelopesID; contractsID
```

2. if files define as many-to-many then i need 3 more tables

```
   1.documents
      1.1 documentsFiles
   2.envelopes
      2.1 envelopesFiles
   3.contracts
      3.1 contractsFiles
   x. Files

   and Files table contain only id; name
```

3. split file table as individual entity and always select as example- work with service or controller

```
    // get
    $source = 'document';
    $data=$this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Documents')
        ->find($id);
    $files=$this->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository('AppBundle:Files')
         ->findBy(array('source_id' => $id,'source'=>$source));

   //save file
    $source = 'documents';
    $uploader = $this->get('uploader');
    $uploader->upload($data->getFile(),source ,$data->getId());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 looks pretty straightforward. Having 3 separate junction tables may seem like a bit of a clutter, but it should not have negative effect on performance.

As another option, may I suggest one Files table as Single Table Inheritance (superclass File, inherited by classes DocumentsFile, EnvelopesFile, ContractsFile), DiscriminatorColumn: linkedto (for example).

In your database schema this would look like:
id, name, linkedto

(linkedto may have values: document, envelope, contract)

[Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

Comment: thanks i try single Table Inherance but this wasn't enough four me, because i also need version control.. so i go with many to many with separate table. anyway thanks for sugestion.